# limiting number of error log dump files retained

Tags: sql-server

SQL server 2008 R2

if I limit the number of error logs retained by setting the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\NumErrorLogs

will this limit the number of dump files retained as well?

Comment: If you are seeing enough dump files that you are worried about it, I think you may have a more important problem to solve...

Comment: yes I do have more important problems to solve, I have corrupted mdf due to vmware upgrades recently made by another department that did not support storage hardware that my databases live on. I'm working on that but in the mean time my C drives on the SQL servers are getting blown out with these dump files, need to limit them while I do restores, etc... and get the databases stable

Comment: I don't think the NumErrorLogs controls the number of dump files.  I see there are undocumented registry values for SQL 2008 under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\<instance-id>\Setup as described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/11/17/how-it-works-controlling-sql-server-memory-dumps.aspx.  The at your own risk disclaimer applies.

Comment: I am not asking how to troubleshoot why these dumps are occurring, I already know why, I just need to stop these dump files from filling up my C drive while I fix the issue

Comment: You might be able use the subst command to temporarily connect a drive with free space to the directory where the memory dumps are being stored.  You'd likely need to shutdown SQL Server to perform the substitution.